# Pre selecting radio buttons using Guid

Tags: jquery, angularjs, forms, radio-button

I have some radio buttons for selecting my problem type , they work fine for saving but when I go back to edit I'd like to have the type I chose pre selected.
I have a list of the problemtypes and the guid of the problem I selected. Should I just loop through the list manually in angular or is there a faster way of doing this?

```
<h1>Select Problem Type</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div ng-repeat="p in problemtypes">
            <input type="radio" name="types" ng-model="problem.Type" ng-value="{{p}}" />{{p.Value}}<br>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you post the code of the controller too?

Answer (score 1):

when using `ng` attributes you don't need to use brackets. also another problem in your code is that `p` is actually an object. so you could approach this in 2 ways:

Using ng attribute: `ng-value="p.value"` 
or using the brackets: `value="{{p.value}}"`

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jepfjbn0/

Comment: I need to save the object, I use it later in angular. I have solved the problem by looping through my list in angular and finding the type by the id  and marking it as checked.

Comment: That's not how you need to work with angular.. you need to use the $scope. as it has a two way binding.